# How do i make shortcuts for IF statements?

Tags: php, if-statement

is there a shorthand version of checking if numerous variables have the same value please ?

instead of :-

```
if ($a="valid")
 {do stuff;}
if ($b="valid")
 {do stuff;}
if ($c="valid")
 {do stuff;}
if ($d="valid")
 {do stuff;}
```

is there something like:-

```
if ($a or $b or $c or $d = "valid")
{do stuff;}
```

Comment: is that a typo or you assigning values inside IF statements? If so, if($a = $b = $c = 'valid')... lol

Comment: typo :D ... should be if($a=="valid") ... my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Conde's solution of putting together an array and then using `in_array` is a good solution.  In case you want to stick with basic string comparisons, somewhat like in your example code, then you could do:

```
if ($a == 'valid' or
    $b == 'valid' or
    $c == 'valid' or
    $d == 'valid') {
  // DO STUFF
}
```

Something to keep in mind, based on what I noticed from your example code: When doing comparisons for equality in PHP, use `==` and not `=`.  The single `=` is for assignment, while the double `==` is for comparison.

Comment: thanks guys ... i am using this style, because i am actually using <> rather than ==

Comment: @Blackwolf - glad I could help.  Thanks for accepting my answer.  I'm still going to upvote John Conde's solution though - it's a good one.

Answer (score 8):

Just put all of the variables you want to check into an array and use [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/in_array) to check them all at once:

```
if (in_array('valid', array($a, $b, $c, $d))) {
    do stuff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extract a function doing the comparison and have :

```
if (check($a) || check($b) ...)
```

It's not as sexy as John proposition (whatever his girlfriend says) I have to admit.

Answer (score 1):

if ($a == 'valid' || $b == 'valid' || $c == 'valid' || $d == 'valid') { // DO STUFF }

This would be best because if first condition is true then no need to check rest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, like this:

```
if (($a || $b || $c || $d) == "valid")
```

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but this would seem to be AND rather than OR though

Comment: I don't have it, this mean ("aaa" && "bbb" && "valid") would be equal to "valid" ? But also "aaa" and "bbb" ?

Comment: [Are you sure that works?](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Z0NOQM) I think [you meant to use `||`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ef3osu);

Comment: @Craftein - I think you never knew this is possible... because this is not possible.  `&&` is the logical `AND` operator.  If you do `$a && $b && $c && $d`, you'll either get `true` or `false` - you will never get a string with value `"valid"`.  If you use the `||` logical `OR` operator for - you'll still run into the same issue.

Comment: okay, crap tastic. none work on my local machine, you sure it's right?

@AlvinLee yeah. just noticed it now. | or || didn't work for OP's question.

funny thing is, if OP's req is all the same, & should have worked.

Comment: @aksu play with String only ;) it won't do the same thing with integers